# Can I set a property like $invalid myself?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I would like to set a property (blurred in this case) on an input element, just like AngularJs sets $invalid, $valid etc. on elements.

Is this possible from a directive, and if so, how?

Comment: Did you take a look at my answer below ? Did it work for you ?

Answer (score 0):

Angular set's properties on the element's controller, not on the element itself.

Controls (e.g. `input`s, `select`s etc) have an **[`NgModelController`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController)**, while `forms`/`ngForms` have a **[`FormController`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController)**.

The `NgModelController` is responsible for informing the parent `FormController` (if any) about changes in properties like `$invalid`.
The directives that use `NgModelController` (e.g. `input`, `select` etc) are responsible for determining when a value is valid or not and call the appropriate methods of their `NgModelController`.

---

For something as simple as setting a property on the controller, you need a directive that gets access to the controller instance (by `require`-ing it) and you are good to go:

```
.directive('blurMonitor', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require:  'ngModel',   // to get access to the controller
        link: function postLink(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {   // ctrl===NgModelController
            /* Initialize the property */
            ctrl.$blurred = true;

            /* Update the property value on focus */
            elem.on('focus', function () {
                /* Since JS events fire asynchronously and outside 
                 * of the "Angular context" we need to call `$apply()` */
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    ctrl.$blurred = false;
                });
            });

            /* Update the property value on blur */
            elem.on('blur', function () {
                /* Since JS events fire asynchronously and outside 
                 * of the "Angular context" we need to call `$apply()` */
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    ctrl.$blurred = true;
                });
            });
        }
    };
});

<form name="form1">
    <input type="text" name="text1" ng-model="something" blur-monitor />
    <p>Blurred: {{form1.text1.$blurred}}</p>
</form>
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/hG37J/)**.